# What class of functions have zero third moment?

Tags: functions

I am looking for a class of functions P(x) which all have the following property:

$\int_0^{\infty}P(x)x^3dx=0 $

which I then want to use as an expansion basis for a function f(x). An example would be:

$P(x)=(4x^4-x^6)exp(-x^2)$

and I expect the function f(x) to be fairly close to this example, so maybe that helps motivate a choice.

Comment: You are looking for examples of formulas for $P(x)$ which satisfy the equation, I suppose? I don't think there's any reasonable 'characterization' of this class of functions.

Comment: Yes, some examples would be a helpful lead.

Answer (score 1):

You can always utilize the Gram-Schmidt process over any infinite sequence of linearly independent functions that includes $x^3$ to obtain the basis you seek, with the added bonus of orthonormality of all members with respect to that integral and not just with respect to $x^3$.

Try it, for example, with a monomial basis ${1, x, x^2....}$. Hope this helps!

Comment: It looks like Gram-Schmidt could be very helpful!

Comment: I’m glad to hear it! Be sure to tick the “answered” box if you feel like I answered your question.